# Проблема с удалением смс

Tags: android

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            if (msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress() == SmsModuleActivity.number)
                deleteMessage(context, msgs[i]);
        }
    }
}

private int deleteMessage(Context context, SmsMessage msg) {
    Uri deleteUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    int count = 0;
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(deleteUri, null, null,
            null, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        try {
            String pid = c.getString(0);
            String uri = "content://sms/" + pid;
            count = context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri),
                    null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

Проверка выполняется. Но смс-ка почему-то не удалется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делать нужно совсем не так.
Во-первых, чтобы "перехватить" СМС и не отдать его другим бродкаст ресиверам, необходимо установить приоритет `intent-filter` в максимальное значение 1000. Хотя если есть другие бродкас ресиверы с таким значением, то кто будет первым в очереди ведомо тока операционке.
Во-вторых, после получения сообщения необходимо выполнить `abortBroadcast` - это прервет передачу данных другим бродкаст ресиверам. Из книги сообщений так удалять бессмысленно, т.к. твой броадкаст ресивер может получить сообщение до того, как его обработает стандартный ресивер, который кладет сообщения в книгу сообщений.
И еще, выполнять абортброадкаст нужно быстро. Точно не скажу, но вроде как он должен быть выполнен по одним источникам в течение 250 млсекунд, по другим аж до 8 секунд. По-этому определение того, должен ли быть аборт или не должен, нужно делать очень быстро. Да еще в другом потоке аборт уже не сделать. Делать нужно именно в потоке где выполняется onReceive

Answer (score 0):

В deleteMessage воткни в catch-блоке вывод исключения:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

Неудивительно, что не можешь понять что не так, если игнорируешь исключения в самом интересном месте...

Comment: Забыл пермишен. Но теперь другое, при приходе смски, удаляет все старые смс с этого номера, а новое которое пришло не удаляет а виснет.